# Excel VBA - Get all href links from a website

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, export-to-excel

[image: Example]

Hi there, hoping that someone can help me.
On this example link: https://www.academiadasapostas.com/stats/competition/brasil/26

I want to get all the href links which are the target of the "VS".
I'm trying examples like this one:

```
Sub ScrapeScores()

Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLTables As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLDiv As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableSection As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim TableCell As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim RowText As String



IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.academiadasapostas.com/stats/competition/brasil/26"

Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE Or IE.Busy
Loop

Set HTMLDoc = IE.document
Set HTMLDiv = HTMLDoc.getElementById("competition-round-group-0")
Set HTMLTables = HTMLDiv.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTables
    Debug.Print HTMLTable.ID, "&", HTMLTable.className
    
    For Each TableSection In HTMLTable.Children
        Debug.Print , TableSection.tagName
        
    Next TableSection
    
Next HTMLTable


End Sub
```

But with no success. I think I could use CSS with a SelectorAll, right? Since IE is going to get extinted, would be nice to use the CSS instead.

Thank you in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following css pattern with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) `.competition-rounds td:nth-child(4) > a`. Loop the returned `nodeList` and extract the `href` from each node. This selects for the 4th column within that table, then the child `a` tag, from which the `href` attribute is extracted during the loop.

---

**Required references:**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library

---

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub PrintLinks()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, nodeList As MSHTML.IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection

    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie

        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://www.academiadasapostas.com/stats/competition/brasil/26"
        
        While .Busy Or .readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Wend
        
        Set nodeList = ie.Document.querySelectorAll(".competition-rounds td:nth-child(4) > a")
        
        Dim i As Long
        
        For i = 0 To nodeList.length - 1
          
            Debug.Print nodeList.Item(i).href

        Next
        
        Stop

        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**Reading:**

1. :[nth-child()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)
2. [Child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator)

Comment: Wow! This works like a charm.
For store on a sheet, it's just to change "Debug.Print" for a code to copy to there, right?
I'm trying to understand the theory of ".competition-rounds td:nth-child(4) > a", in order to replicate to another links.
If the IE is going to be extinted, what would be used instead?

Comment: yes, just change debug.print to cells(row, column) = ....... As for the theory, read the two links. Basically, I am using `td:nth-child(4)` to slice out 4th column of table, then `> a` to get the child `a` tags within that column i.e. those with the links you wanted. Later IE versions will be around for a while but if using VBA you should consider switching to selenium basic with Chrome, or seeing if the content can be retrieved via xmlhttp requests i.e., browserless requests.

Comment: I'm looking on those links, thanks.
I was able to replicate the method on another link, and managed to get the href. Just a slit difference, because, on same rows the item 4 isn't the "VS". But gathering the 3 + 4, I can work out. Here is the link if interested: https://www.academiadasapostas.com/stats/livescores
I didn't know Selenium Basic with Chrome, but definitely I'm going to study it, and maybe use as a solution.
Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to get rid of IE, the following should do it:

```
Sub GetTragetLinks()
    Const Url = "https://www.academiadasapostas.com/stats/competition/brasil/26"
    Dim Html As HTMLDocument, I&
    
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", Url, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With
    
    With Html.querySelectorAll("tr[id*='gsm_id_'] td[title] > a")
        For I = 0 To .Length - 1
            Debug.Print .item(I).href
        Next I
    End With
End Sub
```

Reference to add:

```
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: Thank you. Works perfectly, as the advantage of not having to use IE or even open it, which is great. When I try to replicate the solution to, for instance, this page -  https://www.academiadasapostas.com/stats/livescores , I'm not managing to make it work. Mostly because of the "id", I guess. Can you help on that?

Comment: This `tr td.score > a` might help. If it fails to grab the desired links, feel free to create a new post describing your requirements.

Comment: Yeah.... I toyed with adding xmlhttp attempt. Glad someone added it.